# Automobile license numberplate digits sum

Tags: probability

Four digit vehicle numbers sum up to 18 ...due to a maximum probability from central value as:

$$  (0+9)/2 *4 $$
 Is it correct?

Comment: If $0$ is allowed as leading digit ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers have exactly $\frac{1}{10}$ chance to appear between $0$ and $9$, since they choose numbers randomly. Therefore: $E(X)=\frac{1}{10}*0+\frac{1}{10}*1+...\frac{1}{10}*9 = 4,5$.

Since we add this up $4$ times, **independently:** $4*E(X)=4*4,5=18$ is indeed correct.